# No lightbox works

Tags: jquery, html, css, gallery, lightbox

I was brought in to save this page, but I can not make drastic changes to it, or completely rewrite it. Seems like it is from some sort of a template. I am trying to renew the gallery, implement a lightweight lightbox, but all the ones that I am trying, just don't work. I am not sure if it's because of some old code that is interfering, or I am just sleep deprived and I'm missing a closing quotation mark. I quadruple checked every file call, they're all correct!

[HTML CODE](http://hastebin.com/bemaweledo.xml)

EDIT: I am currently trying LightBox2 ( The original lightbox script. ), but earlier i tried LightGallery.

Comment: please post the exact problem with the code.

Comment: that's what i can't figure out, why it doesn't work, what's the problem.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what do you mean ? Do you not see the styles applied properly ?

Comment: It just behaves like there's no lightbox installed. It opens the image that it is liked to in its one page.

Comment: You need to make sure the paths for css and jsfiles are corrected map to the relative paths to the page.

Comment: i checked them more than 10 times. i just checked again after you mentioned it. they're all correct.

Comment: I believe your paths should have a back slash in front of them. Ex : <link href="/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

Comment: that has never been necessary in my experience, but I tried it and it didn't work. tried `../` also

Comment: Your last resort would be to check in developer tools like firebug to see for any missing files or script error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after going through it the day after in the morning, I still couldn't find why it wasn't working. So I just tried another lightbox gallery, and it worked.